# Popover/tooltip on stacked progress bar using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I can't figure out how to make each section of a Bootstrap stacked progress bar display a popover or tooltip, preferably the former; however, a tooltip would be ok, too.

Outside of the `<div class="progress"></div>` I can make a `<div>` that will show a popover or tooltip like this:

```
<div class="mypopover" title="" data-content="content here" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="title here">click to see popover</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.mypopover').popover();
</script>
```

…however, this does not work:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar bar-success mypopover" style="width:50%;" title="" data-content="victory" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="successful">SUCCESS!</div>
  <div class="bar bar-danger mypopover" style="width:50%;" title="" data-content="so sad" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="unsuccessful">failure</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.mypopover').popover();
</script>
```

How do you get popovers (or tooltips) to work on the sections of a stacked progress bar? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working fine here:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jpdy/) (Bootstrap 3)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jpdy/1/) (Bootstrap 2.3)

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success mypopover" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" title="" data-content="content here" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="title here" style="width: 40%">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info mypopover" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" title="" data-content="content here" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="title here" style="width: 20%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right...once I cleared my browser cache it worked for me - how annoying.

Comment: If you are using Chrome then you can set disable cache when Dev tools is open option from dev tools F12 then on the lower right corner of the window there will be a gear click on it and check the first check box. (Disable cache). If you are using IE open dev tools F12, and in the main menu bar select cache and select always refresh from server. However, in case of IE you will have to set this option each time you open the browser.